# WPF RichTextBox Scroll / Reset to First Line

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I am trying to use `richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0` but it's not possible.

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ScrollToHome](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.scrolltohome%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method does that.